# Use SwiftUI vanished from XCode New Project

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I am running XCode 11.1 (Also on 11.0) on Catalina 10.15

Before upgrading to Catalina I remember having a use SwiftUI Check Box when we create a new project.

As in Apple Tutorial https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views

[image]

However, as you can see this does not exist for me. I have tried upgrading to 11.1 & restarting Xcode

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It went to the **User Interface** setting. You can choose SwiftUI instead of Storyboard.

[image: How to setup new SwiftUI project]